# termination with "without" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence

If you begin now to recognize these potentialities of your deeper mind, **they will take form in the world without.** 

What does the part in the bold mean?

When I read the sentence I was like "without what?"

Comment: Look at the sense [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/without) labels 'adverb' (though CGEL will doubtless label 'intransitive preposition').

Comment: 'Without are dogs' Revelation 22:15. It means they are (belong) outside.

Comment: Here "without" seems to means "outside" just as within = inside. Example: the inner world is often called "the world within" and in that sense, the outside world is being called "the world without" here.

Answer (score 0):

It's adverbial use of 'without'. Check this:
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/without_2

The bold part means something like: 'they will take shape or form in your invisible world' (that is, beyond your visible world)

Hope it helps.